# phpmyadmin кодировка

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

здравствуйте ребята есть вопрос я в phpmyadmin кодировку поставил utf-8 general_ci
но с русскими и армянскими буквами есть проблема показивает ???????????????? вот так помогите пож...

Comment: Можете скинуть скриншот?

Comment: смените кодировку на `utf8mb4` или `utf8mb4_general_ci`